# What are the good industrial roasters and grinders ?

Tags: equipment, roasting, grinder

I would like to know the recommended brands/models for industrial roasters and grinders (targeting 6 Ton per month)

I already know Toper roaster 10 K (it has an economic price about 15k $)
and Toper TKS 36 as a grinder 
There is also Ditting

But I am not sure if there is other economic machines ? 
and which is better for the grinder ? Toper or Ditting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions are hard to answer as the answer may be subjective. Still, as far as I understood that you are mainly after Turkish coffee, why not check industrial coffee producers in Turkey? They have specialized roasters and grinders.

Some keywords in Turkish:

- "kahve değirmeni" -> "coffee grinder"
- "industrial coffee roaster" -> "kahve kavurma makinası".

Comment: Thanks very much, as you said, Toper is a Turkish brand.